# git remove file from repository and old commit

Tags: git, repository

I have a file with private data.
At the moment it's ok because the repository is private.

I would like to make it public but I don't want that this file stay public.

Is it possible to modify commits of this file to remove this file from the whole repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data :p